# Diagonalizability of a matrix condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, diagonalization

I've recently seen the following theorem; $A$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Now, assume $A$ is diagonalizable, then $\Lambda = P^{-1}AP$ for some nonsingular matrix $P$, and $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_{1}, ... , \lambda_{2})$. So it is easy to see that the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $A$, but why are they linearly independent?

Comment: Hint: $P$ is a square, nonsingular matrix, which means its invertible, so...

Comment: There are many equivalent ways of defining a nonsingular matrix.  It would help if we knew which definition you were using.

Comment: Not quite clear: do you know that $P$ is invertible or you want to prove that $P$, consisting of different eigenvectors, is invertible?

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that the eigenvectors are linearly independent, then $P$ is a $n \times n$ matrix of rank $n$. This implies $P$ is invertible. Otherwise, $P^{-1}$ does not exist.

**Note:** The problem arises when you have an eigenvalue with an algebraic multiplicity more than $1$.